# Change retrofit baseurl that initialized in application class with dagger2

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2

I created Application module called `AppRetroServiceModule` to provide retrofit.

```
@Module(includes = NetworkModule.class)
public class AppRetroServiceModule {

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    public RetroService retroService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(RetroService.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    public Retrofit retrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, Gson gson) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl("http://webservise/Srv1.svc/json/")
                .build();
    }
}
```

As you can see baseUrl is hardcoded and fixed. In application component I created getter to get retrofit and other provider, when application component is dependency for other component :

```
@AppScope
@Component(modules = {NetworkModule.class, AppRetroServiceModule.class})
public interface IApplicationComponent {
    RetroService getRetroService();

    Gson getGsonBuilder();

    Context getAppContext();
}
```

I initialized dagger in application class:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private IApplicationComponent component;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
        component = DaggerIApplicationComponent.builder()
                .networkModule(new NetworkModule(this))
                .build();

    }...

    public IApplicationComponent getAppComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

Now in main activity i need to use other `baseurl` to fetching data from server :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IMain.IMainView {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_m);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DaggerIMainComponent.builder()
                .iApplicationComponent(((App) getApplication()).getAppComponent())
                .build()
                .inject(this);
    ...
```

Because retrofit is initialized when application is started, how can i change anytime retrofit `baseurl` when i need to fetch data from servers in other activity or fragment  ?
Sometimes i need to connect to number of servers and fetch data from these server and use in one activity then i need to change `baseurl` every i needed.

Comment: You can use approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205937/how-to-read-hostname-from-meta-data-when-providing-retrofit-in-di-modules/53208494#53208494)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your base url is dynamic then you can use `@Url`. This will help you to pass dynamic base url to your requests.

```
public interface RetrofitClient {

    // Simple call with dynamic url
    @GET
    public Call<YouModelClass> doSomeRequest(@Url String url);

    // Call with dynamic url and request parameter
    @GET
    public Call<YouModelClass> doSomeRequest(@Url String url, @Query("id") String id);

    // Call with dynamic url and more request parameters
    @GET
    public Call<YouModelClass> doSomeRequest(@Url String url, @Query("id") String id, @Query("key") String key, @Query("part") String part);
}
```

And calling code would be

```
RetrofitClient service = retrofit.create(RetrofitClient.class);
Call<YouModelClass> call = service.doSomeRequest("your_dynamic_url_with_base_url");
// and so on
```

Read more at [`Retrofit 2 — How to Use Dynamic Urls for Requests`](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-use-dynamic-urls-for-requests)

Comment: If i use @Url, what will happen to `.baseUrl("http://webservise/Srv1.svc/json/")` that i have created when start application?@Pankaj Kumar

Comment: @sayreskabir Nothing will happen with that part. It will be ignored for these methods and when you will call any service without using `@url`, this base url will be used.

Comment: So does not matter if you set base url or not, if you use `@url` then this base url will be ignored and the url which you pass as the value of `@url` will be used.

Comment: Dude , I am using post method so i got error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Url cannot be used with @POST URL (parameter #1)` . seems i can not use in post method. What is other suggestion@Pankaj Kumar

Comment: This is my method `@POST("GetCI")
    Call<ResponseBody> getCiFloor(@Url String url, @Body JsonObject jsonBody);`  @Pankaj Kumar

Comment: @sayreskabir It works with POST also. You current code is wrong. Use it like `@POST Call<ResponseBody> getCiFloor(@Url String url, @Body JsonObject jsonBody);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184014/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-sayres-kabir).